# Error at inserting session data into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this function to insert a picture data into mysql database, and also the session value was declared at login time, which will not be destroyed until logging out. But, browser showing the error,
Undefined variable: _SESSION . 
Why is that?
Please anyone to help ?

```
public function save($filename, $type, $size){

     global $connect;


       $sql  = "INSERT INTO photograph (";
       $sql .= " filename, type, size, caption ";
       $sql .= ") VALUES (";
       $sql .= " '{$filename}', '{$type}', '{$size}', '{$_SESSION["username"]}' ";
       $sql .= ")";
       $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

       if(!$result){

          echo "Querying failed";
       }

}
```

Comment: It is because your quotes are all over the place and you're using at least one [MySQL keyword] (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) as a column name. You should error check all of your queries and never assume that a query will work.

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the beginning of the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you dont need to do all the `.=` concatenation which then makes the query easier to read.

Second you cannot use double quotes inside a double quoted string as that terminates the double quoted string so use `$_SESSION['username']` with single quotes.

Third I think at least one of your column names is a MYSQL reserved word so if in doubt, wrap the column names in backticks.

Also its a good idea to output the real database error on your failed message, at least while you are in development.

```
public function save($filename, $type, $size){

     global $connect;


       $sql  = "INSERT INTO photograph (
                       `filename`, `type`, `size`, `caption`) 
                VALUES ('{$filename}', '{$type}', '{$size}',    
                        '{$_SESSION['username']}')";

       $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

       if(!$result){
         echo "Querying failed". mysqli_error($connect);
       }

}
```

And finally doing the query that way opens you up to sql injection issues so try to use prepared statements like this

```
public function save($filename, $type, $size){

    global $connect;


    $sql  = "INSERT INTO photograph (
                      `filename`, `type`, `size`, `caption`) 
                VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssis", 
                             $filename, $type, 
                             $size, $_SESSION["username"]);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($connect, $stmt);

    if(!$result){
        echo "Querying failed". mysqli_error($connect);
    }
}
```

Finally, it is bad practice to use `global` in a class as it destroys the encapsulation. Instead pass the `$connect` in this case as a parameter to this method or better still if this class need it make it a class variable

```
class whatever
{

    public $connect

    public function __construct($db_connection)
    {
        $this->connect = $db_connection;
    }

    public function save($filename, $type, $size){

        $sql  = "INSERT INTO photograph (
                          `filename`, `type`, `size`, `caption`) 
                    VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connect,$sql);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssis", 
                                 $filename, $type, 
                                 $size, $_SESSION["username"]);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        if(!$result){
            echo "Querying failed " . mysqli_error($this->connect);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to update this line to be:

```
$sql .= " '{$filename}', '{$type}', '{$size}', '".$_SESSION["username"]."' ";
```

double quotations for $_SESSION array cause a problem inside string double quotations